# unknown host exception

Tags: java, exception, url

```
try { 
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String source="s";
        String source1="s";
        URL google = new URL("http://google.com/"); 
        HttpURLConnection yc =(HttpURLConnection)google.openConnection(); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream())); 
        String inputLine;


        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            source=source.concat(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        yc.disconnect();

    }

long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Total elapsed time in execution of method callMethod() is :"+ (endTime1-startTime));


    } 
}
```

when i tried the above through command prompt
 i got

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: google.com 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) 
at ScagntJavaHttp.httpMakeRequest(ScagntJavaHttp.java:185) 
at test.main(test.java:23)
```

Can any help me in resolving this one?

Comment: can you ping google.com ? are you behind proxies ?

Comment: And have you tried adding the 'www' part?

Comment: No connection to DNS? does it work with normal IP adress?

Comment: Could you indicate which line in your example is throwing the exception? I don't see a call to HttpURLConnection.connect() as shown in the stack trace.

Comment: Cool - found a [forum entry on Java Ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/416274/sockets/java/java-net-UnknownHostException) with the exact same stack trace - dating from: *tadaa*: Aug, 3rd 2010

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's a proxy problem.
Try to see if you have a proxy definition in your browser and then set it:

```
    ProxySelector.setDefault(new ProxySelector() {

        @Override
        public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Proxy connect failed", ioe);
        }

        @Override
        public List select(URI uri) {
            return Arrays
                .asList(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                                  new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost,
                                                        proxyPort)));
        }
    });
```

To see if you have proxy definition in IE, go to Tools - Internet Options -- Connections -- Lan Settings

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `http://` from your host url when you get `java.net.UnknownHostException` and check your internet connection and the host exists (probably safe with google . . .)

Comment: If you remove http://, java.net.MalformedURLException will be thrown. -1 for this answer, didn't helped..