# Java Program to fetch custom/default fields of issues in JIRA

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I have developed a simple java program to fetch the data of issues/user stories.
I want to fetch 'description' field of a perticular issue. I have used GET method to get response but I'm getting errors while connecting to JIRA.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JiraIssueDescription {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    URL url = new URL("https://****.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/41459");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("username", "***@abc.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("password", "****");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

}

}
```

When I run the project I get following error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ****.atlassian.net
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.JiraIntegration.bean.JiraIssueDescription.main(JiraIssueDescription.java:24)
```

Can anyone please help me with the errors. Do I need to implement OAuth ?

Comment: What is the question? Do you use https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14020/HTTPClient/HTTPConnection.html? What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi @jschnasse I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnknownHostException` looks like you have a typo in your URL or are [facing some proxy issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111050/unknown-host-exception) .

1. Does it work in your Browser?
   It should give you some json in response. Like this:
   https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JSWCLOUD-11658
2. You could also test with other tools like curl. Does it work?
   `curl https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JSWCLOUD-11658`
3. Atlassian rest API provides [two authentication methods](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/), Basic auth and Oauth. [Use this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019997/preemptive-basic-auth-with-httpurlconnection) to create a valid basic auth header or try the request without parameters.

The following code demonstrates how it should work:

```
package stack48618849;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.junit.Test;

public class HowToReadFromAnURL {
    @Test
    public void readFromUrl() {
        try (InputStream in = getInputStreamFromUrl("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JSWCLOUD-11658")) {
            System.out.println(convertInputStreamToString(in));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void readFromUrlWithBasicAuth() {
        String user="aUser";
        String passwd="aPasswd";
        try (InputStream in = getInputStreamFromUrl("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JSWCLOUD-11658",user,passwd)) {
            System.out.println(convertInputStreamToString(in));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("If basic auth is provided, it should be correct: "+e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String urlString,String user, String passwd) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user+":"+passwd).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }

    private InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toString("UTF-8");
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations","id":"789521","self":"https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/789521","key":"JSWCLOUD-11658","fields":{"customfield_18232":...
If basic auth is provided, it should be correct: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JSWCLOUD-11658
```

Comment: Hi jschnasse, Thanks for reply. Yes I've tried the same URL in Postman and I'm getting json in response. Do I necessarily have to use any authentication ? Is the format of `conn.setRequestProperty("username"` and `conn.setRequestProperty("password"` correct ?

Comment: The code goes into IOException catch block. So there is no issue with URL.

Comment: [UnknownHostException is an IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

Comment: Oh. When I try the same URL using Postman, it works well. Maybe it works because I've already logged into JIRA on Chrome and it uses cookies for authentication.

Comment: No, I think in case of an authorisation issue you should get a server response of 401. Are you behind a proxy or something? Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111050/unknown-host-exception .

Comment: Hi jschnasse, after resolving proxy issues the code worked well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `HttpURLConnection` way of implementing, you could use `Spring`'s `RestTemplate` in an efficient manner to solve your problem:

Providing you a piece of code that I use, with the JIRA REST APIs:

Create a RESTClient that you would want to use in conjunction with JIRA REST APIs as like the below:

```
public class JIRASpringRESTClient {

    private static final String username = "fred";
    private static final String password = "fred";
    private static final String jiraBaseURL = "https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/";

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    public JIRASpringRESTClient() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        httpHeaders = createHeadersWithAuthentication();
    }

    private HttpHeaders createHeadersWithAuthentication() {
        String plainCredentials = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] base64CredentialsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCredentials.getBytes());
        String base64Credentials = new String(base64CredentialsBytes);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        return headers;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> getJIRATicket(String issueId) {
        String url = jiraBaseURL + "issue/" + issueId;

        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
        return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
    }
}
```

Then you can further re-use these methods as like the below:

```
public class JIRATicketGet {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        JIRASpringRESTClient restClient = new JIRASpringRESTClient();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restClient.getJIRATicket("XXX-12345");
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

This will provide the `GET` response from JIRA, which is in `JSON` format which can be further manipulated to get the specific field from the `GET` response with the use of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Using the JSON that you get in the step above, you can create a POJO class (for example, `Ticket`) and then use it as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Ticket response = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Ticket.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps!