# Java http client to consume the JIRA REST API, I am getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: jira-rest-api

Below is the code that i use, Not sure if I am doing anything wrong and Kind of stuck in here..

try {           // Object jsonMessage = arg0.getMessage().getPayload();

```
        URL url = new URL("https://jira.mycomp.com/rest/api/latest/issue");

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String userpassword = "uname" + ":" + "pwd";
        String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(userpassword.getBytes());
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
        //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write("JIRA-ID");
        wr.flush();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int HttpResult = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println("" + sb.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and getting the below exception

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `HttpURLConnection`, you could very well use `Spring`'s `RestTemplate` to create your own `REST` client to invoke `JIRA REST APIs`. You can refer my sample code from another answer on StackOverflow.

[Java Program to fetch custom/default fields of issues in JIRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618840/java-program-to-fetch-custom-default-fields-of-issues-in-jira/48661334#48661334)

Hope this helps in answering your question through a different approach altogether. Please provide me with any feedback that you have on my code (I would like to develop this even further).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate.

Comment: @devvent, were you able to get my program for your needs? Did that help you solve your problem?

Comment: Your code looks correct, but didnt work me. I am probably behind a proxy server that stops connections to JIRA rest api. Wondering should it always work through code, if it works in postman. Please advise.